# Math Operation using actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, math

i want to make a math application, and i want the answer is not a negative number. I want the first number bigger than second number, so the answer is a positive number.Please help me

This is my actionscript, but the result is the first number is bigger than the second number.

```
    var g:int=1+Math.floor(10*Math.random())
    var o:int=1+Math.floor(10*Math.random())

    angka3.text=String(g);
    angka4.text=String(o);

    periksa8.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,ceksoalm)

    function ceksoalm(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        var t:int=Number(jawaban8.text)
        if (g-o ==t){
            hasil8.text="Benar";
        }else{
            hasil8.text="salah";
        }
    }

    ulang8.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,buatsoalm)

    function buatsoalm(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        g=2 + (10 - 2) *Math.random();
        o=1+Math.floor(10*Math.random())
        angka3.text=String(g);
        angka4.text=String(o);
        jawaban8.text="";
        hasil8.text="";
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var g:int=1+Math.floor(10*Math.random());
var o:int=1+Math.floor(10*Math.random());

//  add this after generating random numbers
if( g < o )
{
    var tmp:int = g;
    g = o;
    o = tmp;
}

// .. the rest of the code
```